# Probability using R

Tags: r

I have set up a pair of die rolling game with codes below but the final part of the code is not working that is to construct a code that can calculate the winning percentage by taking the average of the throws vector. The player wins if a double sixes come up.

```
throws <- NULL
for( i in 1:24 ){
  Die1 <-sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),size=1,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL)
  Die2 <-sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),size=1,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL)
  throw <- Die1+Die2
  throws[i] <- throw  
}
throws
game <- any( throws == 12 ) 
game

for (i in 24){
if (Die1==6 & Die2==6){
throws/2 * 100}
```

Comment: you need to have `Die1[i] <- sample...` and `Die2[i] <- sample...`. then you can loop through the two

Comment: Wrong: `for (i in 24)`; right: `for (i in 1:24)`.

Answer (score 0):

R is vectorized and your problem can be solved with vectorized instructions only.

- To repeat the same code a certain number of times, use `replicate`, not a loop (neither `for` nor `*apply` loops);
- now that `throws` are stored in a matrix, use the optimized `colSums`, it's coded in C, it's simple and it's fast;
- a proportion can be computed as the mean value of a logical vector.

```r
set.seed(2023)    # make the results reproducible

nthrows <- 24L
throws <- replicate(nthrows, sample(6L, 2L, replace = TRUE))
throws
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
#> [1,]    5    3    4    1    5    1    5    3    4     1     6     6     5     2
#> [2,]    1    2    2    1    1    5    2    5    5     1     2     6     1     6
#>      [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24]
#> [1,]     6     5     6     6     6     2     3     6     5     2
#> [2,]     1     4     1     4     6     2     4     1     6     4

game <- any(colSums(throws) == 12L) 
game
#> [1] TRUE

mean(colSums(throws) == 12L) * 100
#> [1] 8.333333
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The following code gives the matrix `throws` row and column names. The rest of the code in the original answer remains the same.

```r
set.seed(2023)    # make the results reproducible

nthrows <- 24L
throws <- replicate(nthrows, sample(6L, 2L, replace = TRUE))
dimnames(throws) <- list(c("Die1", "Die2"),
                         paste0("throw", seq.int(nthrows)))
throws
#>      throw1 throw2 throw3 throw4 throw5 throw6 throw7 throw8 throw9 throw10
#> Die1      5      3      4      1      5      1      5      3      4       1
#> Die2      1      2      2      1      1      5      2      5      5       1
#>      throw11 throw12 throw13 throw14 throw15 throw16 throw17 throw18 throw19
#> Die1       6       6       5       2       6       5       6       6       6
#> Die2       2       6       1       6       1       4       1       4       6
#>      throw20 throw21 throw22 throw23 throw24
#> Die1       2       3       6       5       2
#> Die2       2       4       1       6       4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: throws <- replicate(nthrows, sample(6L, 2L, replace = TRUE))....this codes repeats the expression by selecting 2 elements from one die. But I want to select one die from tossing a pair of dice. So I changed it to the code below but the last two codes does seem to work with my changes nthrows <- 24
throws_1 <- replicate(nthrows,sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),size=1,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL))
throws_2 <- replicate(nthrows,sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),size=1,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL))
throws_1
throws_2
throwss = throws_1+throws_2

Comment: @khali-blinks My code throws one die twice or throws 2 dice once, the difference in how you interpret gives the same final result (since the throws are iid). `replicate` will output a matrix with 2 rows, one per throw. Name the rows `"Die1"` and `"Die2"` and this should become obvious. I will edit with code to name the rows and columns.